# Unhandled ASP.NET Errors

Tags: asp.net, iis, windows-server-2008

We have an issue with a ASP.NET running in production on windows server 2008 and IIS.

Recently I've been getting 1000's of daily errors showing in my log4net file (generated from global.asax Application Error event).

It seems like the website or an external resource is generating 502 bad gateway response.

```
Machine: CYSERVER Framework Version: 4.0.30319.2045 
Assembly Version: 6.5.5498.37473 
Source: http://www.domain.com/Error.aspx?404;http://www.domain.com:80/%3Chtml%3E%3Chead%3E%3Ctitle%3E502%20Bad%20Gateway%3C/title%3E%3C/head%3E%3Cbody%20bgcolor= 
Exception: System.Web.HttpRequestValidationException (0x80004005): A potentially dangerous Request.RawUrl value was detected from the client (="/
```

I've also enabled IIS logs to try and find the source of the error:

```
    2015-01-21 09:39:01 W3SVC2 CYSERVER  62.40.246.26 GET /<html><head><title>502+Bad+Gateway</title></head><body+bgcolor= - 80 - 5.28.182.46 
   HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64)+AppleWebKit/537.36+(KHTML,+like+Gecko)+Chrome/39.0.2171.95+Safari/537.36 ASP.NET_SessionId=l0lfplkbzy42gbt0lktetg5b;+__utma=269413869.1923211166.1367695371.1418038854.1421229175.11;+__utmc=269413869;+__utmz=269413869.1421229175.11.11.utmcsr=TF|utmccn=(not%20set)|utmcmd=pop|utmctr=Register1_aspx;+_TrackIt
   http://www.domain.com/Register1.aspx?affiliateId=1 
   www.domain.com 302 0 0 449 915 137
```

Any tips on how to figure out the source ?

Answer (score 0):

It is clearly saying Register1.aspx is source. Validate and sanitise inputs on this page. Use HTML encode for the same. It is detecting special characters in the inputs received in request and having doubt of Cross site scripting attack. Resolve your issue by input sanitization and do no use ValidateRequest="false" solution. For more information check https://www.owasp.org/index.php/ASP.NET_Request_Validation

You can also write Extended validator to check which parameter is failing and log the same if you are not sure what are the other pages it is having same problem.

Comment: You are basically saying that someone is trying to submit invalid values to Register1.aspx (some sort of "hacker") but the errors are coming from different IPs (from my local country) and i cant believe this is an attack. Is it possible that one of the external resources (javascript or others) on the page fails to load and generates these errors ?

Comment: If it is within your code then every request should be errored out as you mentioned. If any thirdparty application is submitting data then that is not in correct format. Sanitize your inputs. http://www.asp.net/whitepapers/request-validation